# How to end all session when logout

Tags: php

This is my PHP code to end the session but when I click on the back button it still go back into my previous page.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(session_destroy()) // Destroying All Sessions
{
    header("Location: login.php"); // Redirecting To Home Page
}
?>
```

Comment: *"the database i use is oracle"* - ok, and relevance is? here http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Using the back button, the browser will tend to use its local cache if it's able.

Answer (score 2):

Really you should not be able to view a page if you are not logged in. Just do this on the top of every page.

```
<?php
session_start();
//check some value that lets you know if a user is logged in.
if(empty($_SESSION['user_id'])){
  header("Location: login.php")
}
```

the redirect will happen even if your site is cached.

Comment: thx for answer but it seems that i still can go back to the previous page.. only the session id is destroy. @Neoaptt

Answer (score 0):

take a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php

This just deletes all data within session but not the session itself, You have also to delete the session id and the session cookie (setcookie())